# How to map a object of objects getting the key and value?

Tags: javascript

I have map called "marks" that has other maps as fields. I need to do something like a forEach loop (or a map) with this getting the key and the value of each nested map.

This is my data:

```
   "marks" : {
       "mark_01": {x: 10, y: 200},
       "mark_02": {x: 200, y: 100},
        ...
       "mark_99": {x: 1000, y: 1039}
    }
```

What I am trying to do is:

```
 // This is wrong but represents the main idea
 const newMarks = marks.map(mark => {
    // Get the mark key "mark_number"
    // Change its value (x, y)
    // Return an object with the same key and the new manipulated value
 })
```

Any ideas? The resulted data has to look like this:

```
"marks" : {
      "mark_01" : {x: 0, y: 190},
      "mark_02" : {x: 190, y: 90},
       ...
      "mark_99" : {x: 990, y: 1029}
 }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another alternative solution:

```
const edited = Object.fromEntries(Object.entries(marks).map(
    ([k,{x,y}]) => [k,{x: x+10, y: y+10}]
));
```

You can check it here: https://jsfiddle.net/sandro_paganotti/ztw1exb4/13/

Answer (score 4):

Below snippet could help you

```js
const { marks } = {
  marks: {
    mark_01: { x: 10, y: 200, other_if_have: 'a' },
    mark_02: { x: 200, y: 100, other_if_have: 'b' },
    mark_99: { x: 1000, y: 1039, other_if_have: 'c' },
  },
}

const temp = Object.keys(marks).map((mark) => {
  const manipulate = ({ x, y }) => ({
    x: x - 10,
    y: y - 10,
  })
  return [mark, { ...marks[mark], ...manipulate(marks[mark]) }]
})

const res = { marks: Object.fromEntries(temp) }

console.log(res)
```

Ref:

- `Object.keys()` [doc](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys)
- `Object.entries()` [doc](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/fromEntries)

Answer (score 1):

Could use a `for...in` loop:

```js
const marks = {
  "mark_01": {
    x: 10,
    y: 200
  },
  "mark_02": {
    x: 200,
    y: 100
  },
  "mark_99": {
    x: 1000,
    y: 1039
  }
}

console.log("before", marks)

for (let i in marks) {
  marks[i].x += 1;
  marks[i].y += 1;
}

console.log("after", marks)
```

---

Though, you should note:

> The problem with a for...in loop is that it iterates through properties in the Prototype chain. When you loop through an object with the for...in loop, you need to check if the property belongs to the object. You can do this with hasOwnProperty.

So to account for this:

```js
const marks = {
  "mark_01": {
    x: 10,
    y: 200
  },
  "mark_02": {
    x: 200,
    y: 100
  },
  "mark_99": {
    x: 1000,
    y: 1039
  }
}

console.log("before", marks)

for (let i in marks) {
  if (marks.hasOwnProperty(i)) {
    marks[i].x += 1;
    marks[i].y += 1;
  }
}

console.log("after", marks)
```

---

[This](https://zellwk.com/blog/looping-through-js-objects/) is a good article to check out for something like this.

Answer (score 1):

if you have undetermined number of properties inside your object you can do nested for like that

```
let marks = {
  "mark_01": {x: 10, y: 200, z: 300, ...},
  "mark_02": {x: 200, y: 100, z: 10, ...},
  "mark_99": {x: 1000, y: 1039, z: 1200, ...}
}

let newMarks = {}
for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(marks)) {
  let newValues = {}
  for (const [innerKey, innerValue] of Object.entries(value)) {
    newValues[innerKey] = innerValue - 10
  }
  newMarks[key] = newValues
}
console.log(newMarks);
```